# Python threading module not recognizing args

Tags: python, multithreading

For some reason, the folowing error is being thrown even though the one required argument is given.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\josep_000\Desktop\test.py", line 53, in <module>
        a=threading.Thread(target=getin(),args=(aa))
TypeError: getin() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var'
```

Comment: Please post the code you're using. Your question will likely be closed as lacking a reproducible example otherwise.

Comment: It was answered correctly by someone, so apparently I did give enough detail. In any case, I can't share any code for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python [threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) accepts `callable` object as a target.

So when you do this `threading.Thread(target=getin(),args=(aa))`.. Ideally you are passing passing the return value of `getin` being called with no arguments. Since `getin` requires 1 argument this is an error.

You should pass like below...

```
threading.Thread(target=getin,args=(aa, ))
```

Also, `Thread` class accepts `tuple` as `args`...

When you use `parentheses` without any comma inside `Python` just `yields` the value given inside....If you need a tuple with one value you've to add a `comma` inside.

Parentheses without any comma inside gives you a `tuple object` with empty items like below..

```
>>> a = ()
>>> a
()
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
```

If you use `parentheses` having one value inside without any `comma` you'll endup getting like below..

```
>>> b = (1)
>>> type(b)
<type 'int'>
```

If you need a tuple having one value you've to add a `comma` inside..like below.

```
>>> c = (1,)
>>> type(c)
<type 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the parentheses after `getin()`:

```
    a=threading.Thread(target=getin(),args=(aa))
                                   ^^ these need to be removed
```

Currently, your code calls `getin()` directly instead of passing it to the `Thread` constructor to be called from the context of the new thread.

Also, `args` needs to be a tuple. To create a single-element tuple, add a comma after `aa`:

```
    a = threading.Thread(target=getin, args=(aa,))
```